# Can I change the text that's added to the file name when I make a link to it?

Tags: nautilus, symbolic-link

If I make a link to, say, "make believe.mp3", the link is named "Link to make believe.mp3", but I'd rather name it "make believe.mp3 - link", so that being a link doesn't interfere with its alphabetic sorting. Is it possible to change the default behavior?

Answer (score 2):

If you hold the shift and control button while dragging your file to a new location you will get a link. (You'll see a little chain symbol) Basically if you drag to a different folder then it creates a link with the exact same name as the original file, but if you create a link in the same directory then it appends 'Link to' in front of the file name. I don't think you can change that behaviour, but dragging into a different location solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `ln -s` command:

1. Open a Terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)
2. navigate to your directory with `cd /path/to/my/dir`
3. create a link with `ln -s /path/to/your/file name-of-the-link`
   So in your case: `ln -s make\ believe.mp3 make\ believe.mp3-link` 
   Note, that I used a `\` to escape the space in the filename. Otherwise `ln` would interpret the input as different filenames

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for a way to make them the way I want with the right click command.

Comment: As implied by Wayne, it's better to avoid spaces and other characters that need escaping when naming files.